# Gets halfway through creating HTML with XSLT and XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform

I extract the xslt from the xml file first. Then I write the xslt file. Finally, I transform the xslt to html with the following code. However, the html is not fully generated. It seems that an error occurs while reading the base64 code.

```
try {

  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

  Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(_xlst_filename));

  transformer.transform(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(filen),
    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(
      new FileOutputStream(_xlst_filename.replace(".xslt", ".html"))));
} catch (Exception e) {
  transformed = false;
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

interrupted html as if it went into a loop.

```
<td valign="middle" align="center" width="20%">
    <br>
        <br>
            <img src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src=" src="
```

I am new to Java and I could not understand the information requested in the comments and replies. I am sharing the following additional information: "HI02023000042250.xslt; Line #65; Column #9; java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

The following base64 code is causing the HTML to be cut off. This is an e-invoice document from a company. I need to process this XML.

```xml
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"/>
```

Comment: "It seems that an error occurs" - Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `FileOutputStream`, then unless otherwise specified in the API you are using, you are responsible for closing it. Failure to close a stream can mean that data is lost from the end of it. Try constructing the `StreamResult` directly from the `File` object (that is, use `new File` rather than `new FileOutputStream()`).

However, I'm guessing. You say "It seems that an error occurs" but give us no description of symptoms, and without knowing the symptoms, any diagnosis is bound to be a wild guess.